# Function with variable of Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

Let be a function $f= 100e^{-0.25X}.$

Assume $X$ follows Poisson distribution with $λ =0.5.$

What is the mean or expected value of the function $f$?

Since we have a Poisson distribution then mean will be equal to $λ$ and $0.5$ consequently. Can we just plug $0.5$ into equation? This seems really confusing and too easy.

Comment: when you are satisfied with an answer you should accept it by pressing the "v" sign to the left of it.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \operatorname{E} \left(100e^{-0.25X} \right) = \sum_{x=0}^\infty 100 e^{-0.25 x} \Pr(X=x) = \sum_{x=0}^\infty 100 e^{-0.25 x} \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!} \\[10pt]
= {} & 100e^{-\lambda} \sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{\left( e^{-0.25}\lambda \right)^x}{x!}= 100e^{-\lambda} e^{-0.25\lambda} = 100 e^{-1.25\lambda}. \\& \quad \uparrow \quad \text{This can be done because $100e^{-\lambda}$ does not change as $x$ changes.}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You have a function $f$ which associated to any value $x$ the value $f(x) = 100 \cdot e^{-0.25 \cdot x}$. Now you wish to know what the expected value of $f(N)$ is with $N$ Poisson$(\lambda)$. For this you have the following definition:

$$
\mathbb{E}[f(N)] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n) \mathbb{P}\{N = n\},
$$
with $\mathbb{P}\{N = n\}$ the probability that the poisson distribution $N$ is equal to $n$.
For further reference see:

https://imai.princeton.edu/teaching/files/Expectation.pdf

and

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution

Comment: Since the Poisson distribution is discrete, why not use a sum?

Comment: Thank you for your help and time, but what about limits of integration? And how can we apply pdf in this case since it varies from different values of k, I mean p(x=k). I'm really sorry for such stupid questions, I'm just trying to get the idea of Poisson on my own

Comment: You are quite right, I changed it to a sum.

you have convergence here, you can check by calculating $\mathbb{E}[f(N)]$.

Comment: The answer should be clear now, I made a few typos